# Using super+space rotates through apps in bottom

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, cinnamon

I use super+space to switch languages, but recently it started showing me the app previews (or whatever they are called) in the bottom panel
[image: like so]

How can I toggle this off and only use the shortcut for switching languages?
Using Ubuntu 20.04 with cinnamon environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the Open Applications icon and click **Parameters**

[image: Step one]

Click on **Settings**

[image: Step two]

On the hotkey tab, look for **Global hotkey for cycling through the thumbnail menu**

[image: Step three]

Sorry for not finding the English version.